# Rails Simple_form_for hidden_field Value Incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following form in my Rails app:

```
   <%= simple_form_for(@ingredient) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-inputs">
        ...
        <%= f.hidden_field :recipe, value: @recipe.id %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions text-center">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I have this in my controller:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
@ingredient = Ingredient.new
@ingredients = Ingredient.where(user_id: current_user.id, recipe_id: @recipe.id)
```

And I have tested with byebug that `@recipe.id` comes out as a number (`4` in the instance I am testing).

When the form actually gets rendered, the value is correct:
[image]

However, when the record is create the `ingredient` still is created with a `recipe_id` of `nil`.  Any wisdom as to what's going wrong?

Comment: you are looking at the wrong hidden field. yours is inside the `.form-inputs` div, just below that selected hidden input

Comment: @MrYoshiji that is correct and the OP has been updated.  Unfortunately, that makes the problem even more vexing!

Comment: the `f.hidden_field :recipe` should be `f.hidden_field :recipe_id`

Comment: @MrYoshiji YES!  Thank you.  If you write up an answer I'll happily accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f.hidden_field :recipe` should be `f.hidden_field :recipe_id`

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, you should use f.hidden_field :recipe_id

But I will add a plus, try use like this:

Ingredient controller:

```
@ingredient = Ingredient.new({:recipe_id => @recipe.id})
```

In ingredient view:

```
f.hidden_field :recipe_id
```

In this way you don't need instantiate recipe in view. This will work for your edit view too! It keep things clear!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  However, after updating the OP with the correct form-input, the error persists (where the `ingredient` is created with the `recipe_id` of `nil`) even with the html listing a value of 4.